# Best way to implement a messaging system

Tags: android, message

I have got a client-server android app and i want to integrate a small 
messaging tool where users can send messages to other users. It does not 
need to be like a real time chat, it would be enough to act asynchronous 
like email messaging for example.

I just need to know whats the 'best practice' for such a messaging service
for storing the messages. Is it smart to save all the messages and message
history in the database or should they be stored as files on the harddrive
on server side?

Is it enough to save them at the server and load them into the app everytime
the users opens the messaging activity or would it be better to synchronize
the messages? Or shouldnt i store the messages on the server at all and keep the 
history on the device itself?

Comment: Nobody can give you "best practice" since that means that all possible practices have been tested and measured and the best one selected.  You are therefore left with an opinion based question unless you add hard facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 'depends'. Do you expect a lot of messages? If so, synchronizing is probably better than downloading all the messages.

Do you want users to see messages on another device if they switch devices? If so, you have to store the messages on the server.

Also, do you want users to be notified of a message when they're not using the app? Or when another user sends them the message, and not when they start the app? That would require using push notifications.

So - depends.

Answer (score 0):

The best practise would be mainly to use [**GCM**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) for notifying devices about new messages, which requires a server anyway. Once you have a server, it's better to have database to be sure you won't lose any messages.